# Spark SQL function to count the repetation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to achieve the below task using spark sql......

I have a table values like

[image: table structure]

I need the output like

```
1               1 has repeated for 3,3 has repeated for 3 times.....
2               2 has repeated for 3,3 has repeated for two times.......
```

from my end I have grouped the data using row1 to get same id's together

```
scala> val data=rows.groupBy("row1")
```

after that i am not able to split the row2 with "," and count the occurrence of each value...

Could any one help on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split and explode:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(col("row1"), explode(split(col("row2"), ",")).alias("row2"))
  .groupBy("row1", "row2").count
```